# Remove everything from a string after a word from list meets the specific requirements

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to find a way to remove specific words from a list and have the possibility to remove everything from that list after the word has an attached special character after it.

How I currently remove just the specific items:

import re

```
fruits = "Banana Apple Strawberry Cherry Pear Melon Orange"
remove_fruits = "Cherry", "Orange"
fruits_list = fruits.split()
clean_items = []
re_remove_fruits = [fruit for fruit in remove_fruits if "\\" in fruit]
non_re_remove_fruits = [fruit for fruit in remove_fruits if fruit not in re_remove_fruits]
for fruit in fruits_list:
    for remove_fruit in re_remove_fruits:
        fruit = re.sub(remove_fruit, "", fruit)
    for remove_fruit in non_re_remove_fruits:
        if fruit.upper() == remove_fruit.upper():
            fruit = ""
    if fruit:
        clean_items.append(fruit)
cleaned_list = " ".join(clean_items)
print (cleaned_list)

Banana Apple Strawberry Pear Melon
```

How I would like to have them removed:

```
fruits = "Banana Apple Strawberry Cherry Pear Melon Orange"
remove_fruits = "Apple", "Orange", "Pear#"
result = "Banana Strawberry Cherry"
```

Comment: You want to join your 'remove_fruits' with pipe-symbols so you can use them in an alternation, and most likely want to replace '#' with `(?!\S).*`. For example: [`\s*(?<!\S)(?:Apple|Orange|Pear(?!\S).*)(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/x9lXXw/1) replaced with nothing. That being said, maybe there are better ways without regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is something you need:

```
fruits = "Banana Apple Strawberry Cherry Pear Melon Orange"
remove_fruits = "Apple", "Orange", "Pear#"
fruits_list = fruits.split()
special_char = "#"

new_list = []

for each in fruits_list:
    if each+special_char in remove_fruits:
      break
    else:
      if each not in remove_fruits:
        new_list.append(each)

" ".join(new_list)
```

Output:

```
Banana Strawberry Cherry
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple for-loop to do it:

```
fruits = "Banana Apple Strawberry Cherry Pear Melon Orange"
remove_fruits = { "Apple", "Orange", "Pear#" }

good_fruits = []

for fruit in fruits.split(' '):
  if fruit in remove_fruits:
    continue
  if fruit+'#' in remove_fruits:
    break
  good_fruits.append(fruit)

result = " ".join(good_fruits)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
Banana Strawberry Cherry
```

Comment: Thanks this was what I was looking for.

Comment: So why did you accept the other answer which came after mine :)